# Finding out which applications are running Performance tests on K8

Tags: amazon-eks

Problem statement.

I have a Kubernetes cluster and have a variety of applications that are running on the kubernetes cluster. They all share one cluster.

Now I want to know which of the application that are running on the Kubernetes cluster have any sort of Long running performance tests are running. The all mostly run the tests with tools like load runners.

I want to know which of these are running current tests , and then if the applications are not running the tests then reduce the minimum replica to say 1 to just keep the application running but at a very small scale.